# Entity Framework navigation property is null(using T4) but has a value if using Legacy ObjectContext

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, entity-framework, entity

We use a Database first approach. We rewrote our old system that was using Oracle and Legacy ObjectContext code generation strategy with the T4 and Mysql as database.
Due to databinding for MS Forms we followed the Microsoft guide on changing ICollections to ObservableListSource.

The problem that we have now is that the code below works in "old Oracle" system as expected but not in our new T4 Mysql.
So the problem that we have is that right after we added new object to the list, the navigation propery should have a value and not being null.
Lazy loading is on.

ORACLE CODE : LEGACY

```
S_SUMREPORT rep = (S_SUMREPORT)s_SUMREPORTBindingSource.DataSource;
var emails = databaseEntities.S_SUB_CONTACT.Where(p => p.FK_SUB.Equals('code'));
if (emails != null)
{
    foreach (S_SUBCLIPPING_CONTACT c in emails)
    {
        S_SUMREPORT_CONTACT contact = new S_SUMREPORT_CONTACT();
        contact.FK_EXP_TEMPLATE = c.FK_EXP_TEMPLATE;
        rep.S_SUMREPORT_CONTACT.Add(contact);
       ////now the call to navigation property S_EXP_TEMPLATE is NOT null! 
       bool IsActive = contact.S_EXP_TEMPLATE.ACTIVE;
    }
}
```

MYSQL T4 code

```
S_SUMREPORT rep = (S_SUMREPORT)s_SUMREPORTBindingSource.DataSource;
var emails = databaseEntities.S_SUB_CONTACT.Where(p => p.FK_SUB.Equals('code'));
if (emails != null)
{
    foreach (S_SUBCLIPPING_CONTACT c in emails)
    {
        S_SUMREPORT_CONTACT contact = databaseEntities.S_SUMREPORT_CONTACT.Create();
        contact.FK_EXP_TEMPLATE = c.FK_EXP_TEMPLATE;
        rep.S_SUMREPORT_CONTACT.Add(contact);
       ////now the call to navigation property S_EXP_TEMPLATE IS null! 
       bool IsActive = contact.S_EXP_TEMPLATE.ACTIVE;
    }
}
```

Our result:
In oracle the call to contact.S_EXP_TEMPLATE would have a value without in debuger without even executing the call
in Mysql the call to contact.S_EXP_TEMPLATE is null unless we call databaseEntities.Entry(contact). Otherwise calling contact.S_EXP_TEMPLATE.ACTIVE throws null pointer exception.

Note:
Oracle with legacy ObjectContext code generator is creating EntityCollection where T4 is creating  ObservableListSource for navigation properties.
And our Contact is a DynamicProxy

I have no idea what is the "right" way to add something to the dbContext( this is our databaseEntities) when I don't want somethings to be stored but would like to immediately use them.

Basically what we have is a simple form with emails, and for those email you generate pdf based on the export template and if pdf was a success , then you SaveChanges.

But as I said before, navigation property is there only if after adding it to the list (rep.S_SUMREPORT_CONTACT.Add(contact)) we call databaseEntities.Entry(contact)

Is this suppose to work like this ? I read that, yes the value is null, but due to lazy loading the value will become something and not staying null.

Thank you.